# JavaScript function prototype alternatives

Tags: javascript

How can we avoid prototype in the following code?

```
var a = (function(){return { 
               hello : function(){
                           console.log('say hello ' + jello() );
                }, 
                jello : function(){
                          return 'asked for jello';
                }
            };
        }
 )();
 a.hello();
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: jello is not defined(…)

Comment: What about this.jello() ? Will that work?

Comment: thanks, actual error problem was slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't like to use `this` (because of late binding or whatever), you can also write it like this:

```
var a = (function() {

    function hello() {
        console.log('say hello ' + jello());
    }

    function jello() {
        return 'asked for jello';
    }

    return {
        hello: hello 
        jello: jello
    };
})();
a.hello();
```

Another way to do the same thing without using `this` is using a bound variable instead:

```
var a = (function() {
    var api;
    api = { 
        hello : function() {
            console.log('say hello ' + api.jello() );
        }, 
        jello : function() {
            return 'asked for jello';
        }
    };
    return api;
})();
a.hello();
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't defined jello as a function in the global scope, only as a property of the object you're creating, so you need to help specify where to find it: instead of just calling `jello()`, you need to call `this.jello()`.

```
var a = (function(){return { 
               hello : function(){
                           console.log('say hello ' + this.jello() );
                }, 
                jello : function(){
                          return 'asked for jello';
                }
            };
        }
 )();
 a.hello();
```

Comment: Actual problem was slightly different. I will ask a different question.